# How to paste images onto particular faces of a UV map?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm modeling a simple tile for an isometric game. I've UV unwrapped to this: [image: UV map]

I have textures for the top, bottom, and sides of this tile. I just need to paste them onto the UV map, but I can't find any way of doing that.

To clarify: I want to select a particular image I made in GIMP, then copy/paste directly onto a **specific** face of the UV map. I know how to paste an image so it's the background of the entire UV map, but I do not want that.

I've tried exporting the UV map as an image, drawing on that in GIMP, then importing it back, but the map exports with nasty antialiased lines, so that is a very ugly system.

Comment: You will have to edit it externally

Comment: This is usually done by exporting the layout as a PNG.  You can increase the pixel size to get higher res so it doesn't look as nasty.

Comment: Just to be clear, there is no way to apply an image to just specific faces of a UV map? The anti-aliasing in the image is making it difficult to get the pixel-perfect look I want.

Comment: Can I at least disable the antialiasing on the exported UV map, or make it so that the borders of each face are 0px gridlines instead of multi-pixel lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple (but probably limited) way to add an image "pasted" to a single mesh face is this (btw, it needs two separate UVs one for each face, though)

- assign a specific material to each face to be "pasted" an image (select the face, select the material => assign)
- assign the image as texture to the material
- unwrap only that face, and in the image editor, assign to that only unwrapped face your image, again and adapt the nuwrapped face to the image in the UV/image editor, how you like it.
- Then, do the same for the other face.

something like this:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if this method (having lots of materials) could affect performance vs. the usual method? I'm planning on having lots of cubes.

Answer (score 3):

Consider Texture Paint mode editing for the 3D Mesh.

In response to your statement/question [apply an image to just specific faces of a UV map?]

Blender texture paint mode can paint directly on the image to be used for texture mapping.
When a source image has transparent areas you can directly paint on target image leaving the previous background.

[image]

A sphere was uv unwrapped.  Then a material was created with a texture and image source.  First a pig image was used as the source in paint brush mapping stencil mode.  Next a yellow arrow was a source image in stencil mode.

Save your painted image many times during the process.  The image must be written to disk or you will lose your work. Silently.

In this example we painted directly on the 3d Mesh surface, in superior fashion.  You may also paint on the image editor surface in inferior fashion.

There is a learning curve for the many features of texture paint mode, and Blender is always full of surprises.  I would suggest a video tutorial by searching

[Blender Texture Paint]

mode at some well known video site.

Lastly seams can be added before UV Mapping. UV faces pulled off the image.  Texture Image Mapping Extension [Clip] to stop application of texture to a face. This is supplemental information.

Comment: I've made a texture, but how do I apply that texture to the object? It just shows up as pink.

If I set the viewport to Material mode, I can see my texture, but not in Texture mode, so I can't use Texture Paint.

Comment: Suggestion.  Your first goal should be to have any texture show up on the 3D Mesh and then state you know how to achieve that in original post.  Simple case first.  Next more difficult/experienced case.  It is the custom here to ask a specific question and not bring in many questions.  Have you ever had any texture appear in reasonable fashion in texture mapping?  Lastly if you had little time investment in your current texture attempt ..... [DELETE] the material and texture and start fresh to remove accumulated mistakes.  If you feel you need a tutorial video please state that.

Comment: I don't know if I know how to make a texture show up on the 3D mesh. I can make a material show up, but not a texture.

Comment: I suggest a 5 minute video tutorial on texture mapping for first part of your challenge. A first texture map is better than none at all.  You can search here at BSE for non video explanations. You must 3D Mesh UV Map, have the material, add texture, specify type image source, select the image filename, and select UV map mode.  Most people have learned to map a texture and attach texture to a material by video, I suspect.  If we have too many messages here it will be suggested we go to chat.  The famous site that rhymes with loolube  has tutorials on the topic.

Comment: I appreciate that this answer does not involve making a whole bunch of materials like the accepted answer. Strongly recommend this solution! Thank you.